# Get selected value from form.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models - project and todo, and the project contain many todos. I'm trying to write a form that would add a todo to a specific project, that's selected in the tray.

Unfortunately I get an error

> Couldn't find Project with 'id'=

from todos_controller when i redirect to /todos

> @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

/projects/index.html.erb

```
<h1> Задачи </h1>
<% @projects.each do |project_name|%>
<h3><%= project_name.title %></h3>
<ul>    
<% project_name.todos.each do |project_todo| %>
<li>
<p><%=  project_todo.text %></p>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<h1> Новая задача </h1>
<%= form_with scope: :todo, url: todos_path, local: true do |form| %>
<p>
<% form.label :text %><br>
<%= form.text_field :title, placeholder: "Название задачи" %>
</p>
<%= form.select( :project_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, :id, :title)) %>
<p>
<a href="/projects">ОТМЕНА</a>
<%= link_to form.submit  %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render json: @projects}
  end  
end
```

todos_controller.rb

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render json: @todos}
  end
end

def update
end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @todo = @project.todo.create(todo_params)
    redirect_to projects_path
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :projects, :todos
root 'projects#index'
end
```

I also could not display the submit button as a text link.

Comment: Can you add to your **question** the *path* you are visiting when the error is raised?

Comment: In path /todos.

Comment: Can you please add your routes code to your **question**

Comment: Of course, I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify `create` action as

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:todo][project_id])
    @todo = @project.todo.create(todo_params)
    redirect_to projects_path
  end
```

if not works then check params hash from server log and check project_id is present in params or not.

Above will work but I think you do not need to find project if you modify create action as

```
  def create
    @todo = Todo.create(todo_params)
    redirect_to projects_path
  end
```

also define method as

```
def todo_params
  params.require(:todo).permit(:project_id, :title)
end
```

Comment: When I try to add a todo, I get an error `undefined local variable or method ... Did you mean? to_param` in the line   
    `@todo = Todo.create(todo_params)` , and when i change this to 
    `@todo = Todo.create(params[:text])` I send an empty todo

Comment: have you definde method with name todo_params

Comment: no, I copied this, implying that this is the standard method

Comment: Can not send text to a new todo. So far, I've added validation `  validates_presence_of :text` to the model to avoid adding empty todos

Comment: please add other parameters in todo_params same done as for title

Comment: Where I could find better information about the difference between form_with and form_for,  and about methods like select?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller expects a `project_id` parameter which is probably **not** passed! Try to add the project id to your params hash when you trigger the `todos#create` method

Answer (score 0):

params[:project_id] is nil because the form you are submitting for todo, so you need to access project_id as 
`Project.find(params[:todo][project_id])` in create action.
So replace your create action as follow
def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:todo][project_id])
    @todo = @project.todo.create(todo_params)
    redirect_to projects_path
end
Dont forget to include project_id in todo_params method.